# Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3 in VS 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019

I have my project that uses System.Net.Http version 4.3.4 from Nuget. In my *app.config* I have binding redirects:

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.1.1.3" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Projects successfully built and run under VS 2017. I see in a *bin* folder dll version **4.1.1.3**. But when I build an application under VS 2019 and run it I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

And when I check a *bin* folder I see there dll version **4.2.0.0**.

Why does VS 2019 (and also VS 2022) do that while VS 2017 works as expected? Why binding redirects are ignored? I've found this issue on github, but again binding redirects are advised:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24382

P.S. Using framework 4.6.1

Comment: It is not ignored, the CLR wants 4.1.1.3 as directed by the config file.  But found 4.2.0.0, kaboom.  As-is, you'd have to edit the .config file and ask for 4.2.0.0

Comment: Thanx for the answer! The problem is that my application deployed with nuget 4.1.1.3. And if I edit the config file to use 4.2.0.0 my app will look for 4.2.0.0 dll. And in a lib folder there will only be 4.1.1.3. And I will get an error that 4.2.0.0 is not found.